# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de subir muchas veces al playstore una APP con el mismo codigo pero para diferentes clientes?

Tags: google-play

He desarrollado una app en Android Studio con la idea de que sea "personalizada y exclusiva" para cada cliente.

Por tanto quisiera usar el mismo codigo, para subirla al playstore tantas veces como clientes consiga.

La app tendria un nuevo nombre cada vez y solo cambiaria el contenido de algunas variables e imagenes. El resto del codigo se mantendria todo igual.

Es posible subirla al Playstore como una nueva aplicacion con un nuevo nombre cada vez, las veces que sea? asi sea subirla 1000 veces como 1000 app distintas?

Hay alguna posible restriccion? Como se hace el procedimiento para no quedar restringido por google?

Para reutilizar el codigo se clona el proyecto de alguna forma? o se puede guardar de forma que me quede para reutilizarlo en una nueva app?

¿Se le cambia el nombre del paquete y el keyboard o alguna otra cosa?

Gracias por su tiempo. Saludos Cordiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Es posible subirla al Playstore como una nueva aplicación con un nuevo
>   nombre cada vez, las veces que sea? asi sea subirla 1000 veces como
>   1000 app distintas?

Es posible pero cada aplicación debe tener un identificador único que es `applicationId` que es el packagename:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.simusmakron.app"
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Cada aplicación en Google Play tiene su propio `applicationId` y no puede existir el mismo:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simusmakron.app

de hecho en la tienda hay varias aplicaciones que en realidad son la misma pero en las cuales cambian las imágenes y en ocasiones los datos

> Hay alguna posible restriccion? Como se hace el procedimiento para no
>   quedar restringido por google?

No hay restricción en cuanto a la cantidad de apps en Google Play conocida hasta el día de hoy

> Para reutilizar el codigo se clona el proyecto de alguna forma? o se
>   puede guardar de forma que me quede para reutilizarlo en una nueva
>   app?

Es importante cambiar el nombre de paquete y por lo tanto el `applicationId`.

Si deseas administrar un proyecto en el cual puedas generar varias aplicaciones en las cuales sean diferentes en cuanto a los recursos que contiene es importante revises acerca de variantes de productos o **productFlavors**.

[Cómo configurar variantes de compilación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?hl=es-419)

```
productFlavors {
    demo {         
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionNameSuffix "-demo"
    }
    full {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }
    versionfulla {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }
    versionfullb {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }
    versionfullc {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }



}
```